# VBA on HTML Combobox Pop Up Does not Open

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to fill an online form according to the information on an excel file. But i am stuck on an issue. I have to select an option from a combobox that should lead me to a pop up window to allow multiple selections. When i select it pop-up window does not open. Just "Multiple Selections" is written on the combobox.  Could you please advise me on this issue?

**Here is the related area of the html code:**

```html
  <select name="psDelimSystemIDs" onchange="CheckSelectMulti(this,&quot;4609&quot;,&quot;&quot;);">
      <option value="^^"></option>
      <option value="^^395^^">Option1</option>
      <option value="^^404^^">...Option2</option>
      <option value="^^567^^">...Option3</option>
      <option value="^^409^^">...Option4 &amp; 1</option>
      <option value="^^416^^">...Option5 &amp; 1</option>
      <option value="^^413^^">...option6</option>
      <option value="^^417^^">...Option 7</option>
      <option value="^^396^^">Option 8</option>
      <option value="^^426^^">...Option9 &amp; Console</option>
      <option value="^^430^^">...Option10</option>
      <option value="^^436^^">...Option11</option>
      <option value="^^423^^">...Option12</option>
      <option value="^^397^^">Option13</option>
      <option value="^^398^^">Option14</option>
      <option value="^^469^^">...Option15 &amp; Controls</option>
      <option value="^^472^^">...Option16</option>
      <option value="^^558^^">...Option17</option>
      <option value="^^478^^">...Option18</option>
      <option value="^^734^^">...Option19</option>
      <option value="^^479^^">...Option20</option>
      <option value="^^491^^">...Option21</option>
      <option value="^^399^^">Option22</option>
      <option value="^^401^^">Option23</option>
      <option value="^^629^^">Option24</option>
      <option value="^^630^^">Option25</option>
      <option>----------- Select Multiple Systems -----------</option>
    </select>
```

**Here is the my code:**

```
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value = "Option1" Then IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex = 1
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value = "Option2" Then IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex = 8 
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value = "Option3" Then IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex = 13 
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value = "Option4" Then IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex
        = 14
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value = "Option5" Then IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex = 22
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value = "Option6" Then IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex
        = 19 
Else IE.document.getelementsbyname("psDelimSystemIDs")(0).selectedindex= 26
```

**Here is the pop-up link**

https://***link.com/owa.cgi/frmSelectMulti.Body?psLVMYID=4609&psIssueID=&psOpenerLoadTS=1531074546184&psSelectType=1

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  Could you please [edit] your question to make your code etc legible?  [**Here is a link**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to formatting help.

Comment: `clickselection` is not a valid attribute/property for a select element

Comment: Sorry, clickselection was just a trial. changed to the one that causes problem.

Comment: ...I doubt your code is one long line..  (You might need some line breaks in there) Once that's fixed you make a code block by selecting the text and clicking the `{ }` code button.  See these tips on creating a **[mcve]** as well as "[ask]", plus [these tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) for asking questions, from the site's top user.

Comment: `Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("f2").Value [...]`, but what does the code have to do with your stated problem (pop-up window does not open)?

Comment: The link doesn't work assuming *** should be replaced with www.

Comment: Do you need to fire the onchange event as well for onchange="CheckSelectMulti" ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this stab in the dark answering:

1) You may need to fire the associated event as well. Using your test HTML this is what it might look like. I had to use `InternetExplorerMedium` to get the reading from desktop to work. You would just use `InternetExplorer`.

2) Ensure you have the option text correctly specified e.g. `"Option5"` does not exist. It is `"...Option5 & 1"` in the above. Unless there is something I am not seeing/understanding.

```
Public Sub testing()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorerMedium, htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "file://C:/Users/User/Desktop/index.html"  '<==You would use your URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set htmldoc = .document

        Dim b As Object, testValue As String
        Set b = htmldoc.getElementsByName("psDelimSystemIDs")(0)

        testValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")

        Select Case testValue   '<==Use Select case syntax
        Case "Option1"
            b.selectedIndex = 1
        Case "...Option5 & 1"  '<== Ensure correct option text string
            'Other cases
        End Select
        b.FireEvent "onchange" '<==Couldn't test this
    End With
End Sub
```